# ArrayList of type double[] throws IndexOutOfBounds Exception when using get() method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<double[]> coordinatesArray = new ArrayList<>();`

I am trying to get the first index by doing this:

`double[] firstCoords = coordinatesArray.get(0);`

when I run my Android app it crashes with this:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

FYI, coordinatesArray HAS data, that is 100% verified.
but why is that error occurring? anyone seen this before?

**Update:**
the code gets called in my `onMapReady` method from Google Maps API. If `firstCoords = coordinatesArray.get(0);` is commented out, the map will display a Polyline based on the coordinates provided.

This is a picture of my debug windows WHEN THAT LINE IS COMMENTED OUT:

[image: ArrayList of size 22]

```
ArrayList<double[]> coordinatesArray = new ArrayList<>();

PolylineOptions options;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    double[] firstCoords;
    double[] lastCoords;
    double[] receivedDataArray;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


    for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesArray.size() - 1; i++) {
        receivedDataArray = coordinatesArray.get(i);

        latitude = receivedDataArray[0];
        longitude = receivedDataArray[1];

        coordList.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
    }

    options = new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(10).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    mMap.addPolyline(options);

    firstCoords = coordinatesArray.get(0);
    //lastCoords = coordinatesArray.get(coordinatesArray.size() - 1);

    //marker for beginning location
    LatLng firstLocationPointOfDevice = new LatLng(49, -122);

    //LatLng firstLocationPointOfDevice = new LatLng(firstCoords[0], firstCoords[1]);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(firstLocationPointOfDevice).title("Starting Location"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(firstLocationPointOfDevice));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(firstLocationPointOfDevice, 10));
}
```

now when I uncomment that `firstCoords = coordinatesArray.get(0);` and run the code, the following stack trace occurs when I run my MapActivity class:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: vatracking.project.vatrackingapp, PID: 10898
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                      at vatracking.project.vatrackingapp.MapActivity.onMapReady(MapActivity.java:122)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                      at fh.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529017@12.5.29 (040300-192802242):20)
                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529017@12.5.29 (040300-192802242):5)
                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529017@12.5.29 (040300-192802242):5)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: And you are 100% sure this has to do with your arraylist and not something else?

Comment: if the jvm says size is zero... is because there are no elements on it.
there is no error on that.

Comment: that's means the `coordinatesArray` got cleared from somewhere else.

Comment: Post the code...

Comment: like they say before, cordinatesArray might have been cleared somewhere else. so I suggest you use immutable variables.

Comment: Either `coordinatesArray`  got cleared or was never populated, please post the relevant code.

Comment: And also print a log of your array size before access.

Comment: I have added the code as well as the stack trace sorry should've added that from the start

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very very simple. When an activity in Android is loaded that contains `onMapReady` method, it is automatically called. In my case, `onMapReady` contained an ArrayList with data which was calling a `get()` method to retrieve something from an array but if there is **no data in the arraylist** then it throws an error.

In my case, I was missing a check to see if data exists in the ArrayList, so that's exactly what fixed the issue.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        double[] firstCoords;
        double[] lastCoords;
        double[] receivedDataArray;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


        for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesArray.size() - 1; i++) {
            receivedDataArray = coordinatesArray.get(i);

            latitude = receivedDataArray[0];
            longitude = receivedDataArray[1];

            coordList.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
        }

        options = new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(10).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        mMap.addPolyline(options);

        // if user selected date in date-time picker then marker will point to
        // first set of coordinates in the coordinatesArray and the map will zoom in on that point
        if(!coordinatesArray.isEmpty())
        {
            // get first set of coordinates from array as starting position
            firstCoords = coordinatesArray.get(0);

            // get last set of coordinates from array as ending position
            lastCoords = coordinatesArray.get(coordinatesArray.size() - 1);

            // place marker for starting position
            LatLng firstLocationPointOfDevice = new LatLng(firstCoords[0], firstCoords[1]);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(firstLocationPointOfDevice).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).title("Starting Location"));

            // place marker for ending position
            LatLng lastLocationPointOfDevice = new LatLng(lastCoords[0], lastCoords[1]);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lastLocationPointOfDevice).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)).title("Ending Location"));

            // zoom in on first set of coordinates form coordinatesArray
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(firstLocationPointOfDevice));

            // camera zoom in position
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(firstLocationPointOfDevice, 10));
        }
        // if user did not select any date from date time picker, then by default the map will zoom on vancouver
        else if(coordinatesArray.isEmpty())
        {
            // default location if no date is selected
            LatLng defaultLocation = new LatLng(49.2827, -123.1207);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(defaultLocation));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, 10));
        }
    }
```